# Learning UIPageControl using Apple's "PageControl"sample, need help modifying to add my view controllers

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, uipagecontrol

Using the Apple "PageControl" as a template.  I'd like to know how to modify the code to use my view controllers that I have in my Storyboard.  Let's call the view controllers, one_vc, two_vc, three_vc.  The sample is using NULL for the view controllers.

The full code is here: [Apple PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)

Thanks in advance

-PaulS.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // load our data from a plist file inside our app bundle
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content_iPhone" ofType:@"plist"];

    self.contentList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // view controllers are created lazily
    // in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on demand
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    self.viewControllers = controllers;

    [controllers release];

    // a page is the width of the scroll view
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
    pageControl.currentPage = 1;

    // pages are created on demand
    // load the visible page
    // load the page on either side to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling
    //
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
{
    if (page < 0)
        return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
        return;

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

   // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

        NSDictionary *numberItem = [self.contentList objectAtIndex:page];
        controller.numberImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[numberItem valueForKey:ImageKey]];
        controller.numberTitle.text = [numberItem valueForKey:NameKey];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the controllers in the StoryBoard are inherently linked with the .h and .m files.  I think you will have to create xibs for each of them, and load those instead.